# Leibniz integral rule implementation

Tags: integration, derivatives

Can someone please explain to me why the following expression is true? I really tried to figure out how [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) works, but everytime I think I managed to figure out how to implement it, I never get it right.

$$
V(D) = \int_0^D \tilde{x}dF(\tilde{x}) + \int_D^{I^*+D}(D+(\tilde{x}-D)z_1)dF(\tilde{x}) + \int_{I^*+D}^X(D+I^*z_1+(\tilde{x}-D-I^*)z_2)dF(\tilde{x}) 
$$
$$
V`(D) = -\int_D^{I^*+D}(z_1-1)dF(\tilde{x}) + \int_{I^*+D}^X(1-z_2)dF(\tilde{x}) 
$$

Thanks a lot